# How to make better looking lights/lightbulbs

Tags: lighting

Just throwing an emission shader just yields a completely solid light, which i don't want. Throwing a glass-like shader on a bulb made around a light (via emission) basically just shows the light and the glass would be nearly invisible.

Not like this:

[image]

Something like this:

[image]

[image]

(The brighter bulb, on the right)

[image]

Comment: welcome to [blender.se], please note that there are formatting tools to import images from imgur.  It is important to properly format your question in order to entice others to answer it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to look, whre does the lightbulb really emit light and model this part, and make the outer part really out of glass. Try to do verything like it looks in a real lightbulb and then tweak your values until youre happy. Except they are in a far distance, then you might just use an light source in form of  bulb in purpose of shorter render times.

Answer (score 0):

Edison bulbs have tungsten filament in them that's how they emit orangey light while heated.

Model that filament and set that as an emission object. You can insert the filament's temperature in blackbody shader and give that as a input for color of your emission shader of heated filament.

You can use glass shader for outer body, but it will cost higher for render times, so i recommend you to make a fake glass shader.you can search that on internet.

If you don't want to make it then you can enable cycles material library addon and import fake glass node group. This addon comes inbuilt with blender.

If you are using eevee, mesh lighting would not work. So you will have to place a point lamp near filament and set the same colour as filament.
The emission shader of filament will not be able to lighten up other objects in eevee. But turn on the bloom and you will be able to see it glow because of the emission shader